# How should one structure code when have two branches to branch into

Tags: c, unix, daemon

Say, I one writes a daemon.
Has two options and does not know which to choose from:

**OPTION 1**:

```
int
main(void)
{
    /* Do something with run_as_daemon variable */
    if (run_as_daemon) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
            err_exit("Could not fork to create daemon");
        if (pid > 0)
            exit(0); /* exit if parent */
    } else {
        do_task(); /* Perform some IO using user commands */
    }
}
```

**OPTION 2**:

```
int
main(void)
{
    if (run_as_daemon) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
            err_exit("Could not fork to create daemon");
        if (pid > 0)
            exit(0); /* exit if parent */
    }
    do_task(); /* Perform some IO using user commands */
}
```

I understand that they do the same thing but want to know to to better structure code to make it easier to maintain and read.

Comment: Your premise that these two programs are equivalent ("do the same thing") is incorrect.  There is a difference between the two programs.  In Option 1, `do_task()` is only invoked if `run_as_daemon` evaluates to `false`.  The child process will not invoke the call to `do_task()`  In Option 2, `do_task()` is invoked regardless of what `run_as_daemon` evaluates to.

Comment: Personally I used to use first option. It is fully managed and better understandable by "readers".

Comment: You should manage `pid==0` and `exit` that case too to make solutions equivalent

Comment: The two are not equivalent for a successfully launched child i.e. if `fork()` returns zero.

Comment: Emphasis here not on correctness but on the way how to structure the program. I mean: "should one included `else` explicitly(via else) or implicitly(continuation after condition check).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are applicable in this situation, however the first option creates more readable code in my opinion as you are implying that one of either branches can be taken and that it is not possible to drop down into do_task() if run_as_demon != 0